# Why background image is not visible in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

I'm using a 1280×850 image for background. With this CSS:

```
body {
 line-height: 1;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 background:url(../images/bg.png) no-repeat bottom left;
}
```

Everything is ok in all browsers but not in Firefox. In Firefox, body background is white and background image is not visible. (I'm using meyer css reset).

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried a force-refresh? (Ctrl+F5 on Windows, Cmd+Shift+R on Mac)

Comment: I think its a problem with height. With height for example 800px for body, background imge is visible. (100% height not works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to put some content in the body or set a height. Since your image is 850px tall use,

```
min-height:850px;
```

Comment: Yes, min-height has solved the "height" problem but this time a scroll visible in browser.

Comment: Then use height:100%; You're saying it doesn't work but it works for me.